# ¿Cual sería la mejor traducción para "mock-up"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

En el mundo de UX (de *User eXperience* <sup><sub>1</sub></sup>) es habitual hablar de *mock-ups*, *wireframes*... términos que se suelen utilizar en inglés, cuando seguramente tengan una buena traducción al español.

Por ejemplo, en una exposición que acabo de visitar se traducía *mock-up* como "maqueta". El caso concreto era una prueba de cómo quedaría la portada de la revista *LIFE* superponiendo los elementos de portada a una fotografía.

¿Qué término en español creéis que sería el más apropiado?

<sub><sup>1</sup> Es decir, todo lo relacionado con la interactuación entre el usuario y un entorno, dispositivo o aplicación concretos, y la percepción que aquél tiene de éstos. Véase [Experiencia de usuario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiencia_de_usuario).</sub>

Comment: ¿Podrías dar más contexto de cómo usáis _mock-up_ en UX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con una imagen de fondo y tres o cuatro titulares, podemos hacer un ***boceto*** (o ***bosquejo***) de cómo quedaría la portada de la revista *LIFE*.

> [**boceto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5jB61Ln)
>
> 1. m. Proyecto o apunte general previo a la ejecución de una obra artística.
> 2. m. Esquema o proyecto en que se bosqueja cualquier obra. El boceto de un libro, de una ley.
> 3. m. Exposición sucinta de los rasgos principales de algo.
>
> [**bosquejo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5xN94f7)
>
> 1. m. Traza primera y no definitiva de una obra pictórica, y en general de cualquier creación intelectual o artística.

Alguna vez lo he usado y creo que cuadra bastante bien.

Comment: Yo creo que "boceto" encaja mejor con *wireframe* que es bastante esquemático. Un *mockup* es más visual y detallado. Yo creo que podría valer en un contexto donde no haya varias fases de prototipado.

Answer (score 7):

En informática es habitual usar los siguientes términos (al menos en España):

**Maqueta** para referirse a algo destinado a *mostrar el aspecto* que tendría el producto final, aunque no funcione.

**Prueba de concepto** para describir algo cuya finalidad es *comprobar el funcionamiento* de un programa o sistema, aunque la apariencia no sea la del producto final.

En este sentido, *mock-up* equivale a *maqueta*.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Si no funciona, maqueta. Si medio funciona, prototipo

Answer (score 2):

Los entrenamientos para situaciones de desastre se denominan *mock disaster* que se podría traducir como **desastre fingido**. Es un ejercicio que simula una situación imprevista.

¿**Maqueta**, **simulación**? No sé con qué quedarme.